# orientation in activitygroup with tabbar

Tags: android, android-layout, orientation

orientation change is not working when I rotate a child activity to landscape. I added `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden` in all activity tags in my manifest.xml file.

I found that my app doesn't take layoyt file from layout_land folder. what is the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

By putting that in your manifest you are saying that you will manually handle all orientation changes. You'll have to `setContentView` again `onConfigurationChanged` OR remove it from your manifest and it will load the right layout.

Edit: found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135570/device-orientation-change-doesnt-change-layout) afterwards which explains it

Comment: I removed onConfigurationChanged from menifest. But child activity still not working. when I change to landscape it goes to parentActivity.

Comment: Here is how to store and restore child fragment state: (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9646622/833647). You can also call `setRetainInstance(true);` in the `onCreate()` of your fragment (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11318942/833647)